# why am I getting props unique keys error with undefined variable?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to figure out why I am getting props unique keys error when `_id` is unique, and when I tried to debug `items[key]._id` twice, and undefined why? am I missing something here?

error
[image: error]

```
const arr = [
  {
      "demo": [
          {
              "_id": "xx122",
              "name": "Historian",
              "tags": [
                  "demo"
              ],
              "things": [],
              "list": [],
              "queries": [],
              "notes": []
          }
      ],
      "demo_2": [
        {
            "_id": "xx123",
            "name": "Demo",
            "tags": [
                "demo_2"
            ],
            "things": [],
            "list": [],
            "queries": [],
            "notes": []
        }
    ],
  }
]


  const modArray = Object.keys(arr[0]).map(i => {
    return {id: i, ...arr[0][i]}
  });
    
  export default function Demo() {
    return (
        <div>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {modArray.map((i) => (
                            <th key={i.id}>{i.id}</th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {modArray.map((items) => {
                            return Object.keys(items).map((key) => {
                                console.log(items[key]._id);
                                return <td key={items[key]._id}>{items[key]._id}</td>;
                            });
                        })}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mistake in creating modArray. `arr[0][i]` is `array` type so when you use spread operator inside `{}`, it will be stored something like `{0: {}}`. I've simplified your code.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    demo: [
      {
        _id: 'xx122',
        name: 'Historian',
        tags: ['demo'],
        things: [],
        list: [],
        queries: [],
        notes: []
      }
    ],
    demo_2: [
      {
        _id: 'xx123',
        name: 'Demo',
        tags: ['demo_2'],
        things: [],
        list: [],
        queries: [],
        notes: []
      }
    ]
  }
];

const keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {keys.map(i => (
              <th key={i}>{i}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            {keys.map(key =>
              arr[0][key].map(item => <td key={item._id}>{item._id}</td>)
            )}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React from "react";

const arr = [
  {
    demo: [
      {
        _id: "xx122",
        name: "Historian",
        tags: ["demo"],
        things: [],
        list: [],
        queries: [],
        notes: []
      }
    ],
    demo_2: [
      {
        _id: "xx123",
        name: "Demo",
        tags: ["demo_2"],
        things: [],
        list: [],
        queries: [],
        notes: []
      }
    ]
  }
];

const modArray = Object.keys(arr[0]).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return [...acc, ...arr[0][cur]];
}, []);
export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {Object.keys(modArray[0]).map((key) => (
              <th key={key}>{key}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {modArray.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                {Object.keys(modArray[0]).map((key) => (
                  <td key={`${index}_${key}`}>{String(item[key])}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the console is not an error, it's a warning. Meaning that your components will be rendered but it's important to have unique key values for each element because "Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed."

With that aside, the problem comes when you created your array in the first place. Here is how it looks like:

[the array you're mapping over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfBxg.png)

in your first outer mapping, items will be an object of 2 properties. The first is the item object and the second has an "id" key with the value of "demo". That's what you'll get when if you log (items) to the console

[the values you have in the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Di4.png)

And clearly, id property does not have and _id property. It is not an object in the first place.

Now, this is the reason for having "undefined". To solve it, you need to go back and make sure you're constructing your array the right needed way.